# Как на js сделать перемещение блока по вертикали в пределах высоты родительского?

Tags: javascript

```js
$(function(){
  

var ie = 0;
var op = 0;
var ff = 0;
var browser = navigator.userAgent;
if (browser.indexOf("Opera") != -1) op = 1;
else {
    if (browser.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) ie = 1;
    else {
        if (browser.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) ff = 1;
    }
}

var navscroll = document.getElementById('navscroll');
var overview = document.getElementById('overview');
var rectOverview = overview.getBoundingClientRect();
delta_x = 0;
delta_y = 0;


navscroll.onmousedown = saveY;
if (op || ff) {
    navscroll.addEventListener("onmousedown", saveY, false);
}
document.onmouseup = clearY;
/* При нажатии кнопки мыши попадаем в эту функцию */
function saveY(obj_event) {
    /* Получаем текущие координаты курсора */
    if (obj_event) {
        y = obj_event.pageY;
    }
    else {
        y = window.event.clientY;
        if (ie) {
            y -= 2;
        }
    }
    /* Узнаём текущие координаты блока */
    y_block = navscroll.offsetTop;
    /* Узнаём смещение */

    delta_y = y_block - y;
    /* При движении курсора устанавливаем вызов функции moveWindow */
    document.onmousemove = moveBlock;
    if (op || ff)
        document.addEventListener("onmousemove", moveBlock, false);
}
function clearY() {
    document.onmousemove = null; // При отпускании мыши убираем обработку события движения мыши
}
function moveBlock(obj_event) {
    /* Получаем новые координаты курсора мыши */
    if (obj_event) {

        y = obj_event.pageY;
    }
    else {

        y = window.event.clientY;
        if (ie) {
            y -= 2;
            /*x -= 2;*/
        }
    }
    /* Вычисляем новые координаты блока */

    new_y = delta_y + y;
    navscroll.style.top = new_y - rectOverview.top + "px";

}
})
```

```css
.nav-updown {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -30px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;   
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="viewport" id="overview">
      <p>Любое содержимое</p>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div class="nav-updown" id="navscroll">
                           
                        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что-то типа такого `new_y = Math.max(0, new_y); new_y = Math.min(new_y, rectOverview.height-navscroll.offsetHeight);` , но у вас там статическая ошибка в координатах наблюдается. И чтобы он нормально "ходил" лучше его `absolute` сделать, а не `fixed`

Comment: да, так почти почти получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не смущает использование JQueryUI, то там есть отличный метод [draggable](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/). С ним весь Ваш код превращается в одну строчку.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#navscroll").draggable({ axis: "y", containment: "#overview" });
})
```

```css
.nav-updown {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 30px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;   
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="viewport" id="overview">
      <p>Любое содержимое</p>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div>
        
Что такое Lorem Ipsum?

Lorem Ipsum - это текст-"рыба", часто используемый в печати и вэб-дизайне. Lorem Ipsum является стандартной "рыбой" для текстов на латинице с начала XVI века. В то время некий безымянный печатник создал большую коллекцию размеров и форм шрифтов, используя Lorem Ipsum для распечатки образцов. Lorem Ipsum не только успешно пережил без заметных изменений пять веков, но и перешагнул в электронный дизайн. Его популяризации в новое время послужили публикация листов Letraset с образцами Lorem Ipsum в 60-х годах и, в более недавнее время, программы электронной вёрстки типа Aldus PageMaker, в шаблонах которых используется Lorem Ipsum.

        
      </div>
      <div class="nav-updown" id="navscroll">
                           
                        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: этот вариант я уже пробовал, у меня в проекте так не  работает,  поэтому пытаюсь на js реализоваться.